# Multithreaded database access query

Tags: c#, mysql, multithreading

How can I execute multiple SELECT queries from single database table at the same time? Can I just normally do multiple queries using threads or tasks and with different order/sorting criteria or will it be a problem? For example I have table with player names goals scored and assists. Can I retrieve goal and assist data at the same time with different threads? And is it the same with two different tables in one database? I know that for inserting, updating and removing data it will be a problem but for only selecting them it shouldn't be I think, but I am not sure if it can retrieve data when they are in different order from another query or these two queries are totally independent.

Thanks for help!

Comment: What issue are you specifically having?

Comment: Database engines keep track of connections and can handle numerous connections at the same time if that is the issue you are worrying about.

Comment: So with one connection I can't do it multithreaded but I need to make 2 same connections at one time?

Comment: Generally yes, you need one connection per simultaneous query

Comment: Ok thanks! I am new to it and I wasnt sure. So that is the way how to do it

Comment: @juraj Keep in mind that you can do numerous "sequential" queries through a single connection and once the connection is established, the queries will be very fast. Also, remember to close each connection when finished with it. I would be very careful about opening too many connections at a time, especially if other processes use the same db.

Comment: So if there are few thousands rows, will it be more efficient to do e.g. 5 querries sequentally or make a new connection for each, maybe for each 2? Or how can I than effectively use threads with database?

Comment: Unclear what the "issue" really is - multiple concurrent queries happen in web apps - so whatever (best) practices there would apply. It's not cookie cutter and depends on use cases - e.g. can the dataset be cached? vs direct db queries each time? where? client side?

Comment: What client/UI/user can go through 5k results/rows in "one" go? IOW, think about how to efficiently query result sets _before_ thinking about "multi-threading"

Comment: @juraj Is this going to be a one shot load? Or is this going to be an ongoing thing with lots of user loading thousands of rows all the time?

Comment: it will be one shot load

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I execute multiple SELECT queries from single database table at the same time?

Just do it. Use a separate [MySqlConnection](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connections-string.html) for each query:  Connections themselves are not thread-safe. But you can create a connection, or use one from a [connection pool](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connections-pooling.html), in each thread or process. Satisfying concurrent queries efficiently from different connections is a core feature of all database servers.

> Can I just normally do multiple queries using threads or tasks

Yes.

> and with different order/sorting criteria

That is no problem.

> I know that for inserting, updating and removing data it will be a problem

It can be, but usually isn't. Databases have transactions.